# How to get the string prepended with # and numbers?

Tags: shell

I tried a small program to get the string prepeded with #, but I couldnot get the sring.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        char*path = argv[1];
        printf("\n path : %s \n",argv[1]);
        return 0;
}

root@rs]# ./a.out #1angus

 path : (null)
```

How to get the string prepended with # and numbers ?

Answer (score 2):

Just quote it so the shell doesn't think it's a comment:

```
./a.out '#1angus'
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of these 3 should work

```
./a.out '#1angus'

./a.out "#1angus"

./a.out \#1angus
```